# Possibility to change Itinerary

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, itineraries

I would like to know after I got the schengen visa and If I have already starred the trip, Can I travel a country  which has not include in the itinerary Within the trip.
Thanks

Comment: Which country specifically?

Answer (score 1):

A Schengen visa authorizes you to travel anywhere in the Schengen area, within the dates and length-of-stay restrictions printed on it.

If you go and do something wildly different from what you claimed in your visa application you wanted to do, and authorities find out about that, they *might* end up concluding that *your visa application was a lie even when you filed it*, and hit you with some consequences for lying on the application.

On the other hand, changes of plans are allowed. If you change your plans but you can (if challenged) convince the authorities that it's an honest change of plans that you didn't foresee when you applied, and which doesn't change the general purpose or character of your visit, then you have done nothing wrong.

It all depends on how good an explanation you have **if** you're challenged along the way; there are no bright lines to argue from. But it is rather unlikely that you *will* be challenged -- a random policeman doing spot checks will not have easy access to the particular details of your visa application.

Comment: It will help if your change of plan sounds reasonable, e.g. going through Austria rather than Switzerland on a road trip from Rome to Hamburg. A few miles further east or west is no big difference. It would look bad if you decide to detour through Spain on that route ...

Comment: Just for emphasis, you must obey both the dates and length-of-stay restrictions on your visa. If you stay within the date range but exceed the number of days listed, you'll still have overstayed. This is a common area of confusion, so I just want to emphasize it.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you would visit another country in the Schengen zone, this is allowed with the Schengen visa.